# R: Relationship between McFadden & Nagelkerke

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate Nagelkerke R-square based upon the output produced.  I know that I can calculate McFadden R-square directly.  But Nagelkerke produces what we feel is a more accurate strength of the model.
I am not having luck with adding on packages to my setup, if that is the line of thought that you have.

Thanks.

Comment: The `pscl` package contains a function (`pR2`) for estimating several pseudo R^2 statistics. Be warned that "Nagelkerke produces what we feel is a more accurate strength of the model" is an oversimplification of difficulties associated with evaluating GLMs in a manner analogous to linear models...

Comment: there are a variety of packages that compute pseudo-R2 measures. (`library("sos"); findFn("Nagelkerke")`).  Which ones have you tried, and what hasn't worked?

Comment: When I typed the findFn, it could not find it-it doesn't exist.  I also tried the pR2 function with no success.

Answer (score 1):

This question is underdefined so I'll do my best assuming that "the output produced" is a `glm` object. This function should produce the appropriate pseudo-R square you want when applied to a `glm` object.

```
Nagelkerke <- function(mod) {
  l_full <- exp(logLik(mod))
  l_intercept <- exp(logLik( update(mod, . ~ 1) ))
  N <- length(mod$y)
  r_2 <- (1 - (l_intercept / l_full)^(2/N)) / (1 - l_intercept^(2/N))
  return( as.numeric(r_2) )
}
```

Example:

```
model <- glm(formula = vs ~ mpg + disp, family = binomial("logit"), data = mtcars);
Nagelkerke(model);
#[1] 0.6574295
```

Comment: I saw this, but when I typed Nagelkerke(model), I got an error messgae saying there was no such function.